# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_apply'

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas with version 0.23.4 and the below code is giving me the error - "module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_apply'"

Below is the function call:

```
df['perLow'] = pd.rolling_apply(df.low, 2, add_percentage_diff)
```

Any help with fixing this error is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `pd.rolling_*` family of functions were replaced by [`Rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html#pandas-dataframe-rolling) objects associated with DataFrames around v0.18.

Use [`Rolling.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html#pandas-core-window-rolling-apply):

```
df['low'].rolling(2).apply(add_percentage_diff)
```

Comment: This is sad, since rolling_apply (probably?) allowed to iterate Series of strings, but rolling only allows numeric data. Do you know who I could roll over a Series of strings?